# About Page example question is "How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, help-center

It's probably not good to encourage users to ask questions that are wildly off-topic for the site.

Not sure when this got changed/borked, but it was working correctly a week or so ago when I looked last.

Comment: I'm going to bet it was triggered by my deleting the "thanks!" comment that was being used as the example comment on the about page.

Comment: The tags lie! http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/unicorns |http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/daisies

Comment: Interestingly, this is also [visible at christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's the "You didn't select any questions" default question. Because Unicorn.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's a reference to [James Thurber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unicorn_in_the_Garden) although that unicorn preferred roses.

Answer (score 16):

I've chosen a question out of the list that was given and reset it. I couldn't find the question that was there previously.

I do, however, suspect that the unicorns ate it because somebody denied them their delicious daisies.